# Can't find binary, but path included in $PATH

Tags: path, mercurial

So I tried to install Mercurial on Ubuntu 10.04.
First I used the ppa repo, but got a [pythonpath](https://serverfault.com/questions/234718/cannot-install-mercurial-properly-pythonpath-error) error, which I gave up on.
Next try was install from source, everything went well, except it can't find hg:

```
$ hg
-bash: /usr/bin/hg: No such file or directory
```

However, hg is installed in /usr/local/bin/ :

```
$ which hg
/usr/local/bin/hg
```

The PATH includes this directory, so why is hg not found?

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

If I execute hg with the full path it works:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/hg --version
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bash maintains a cache of locations of executables in `$PATH`. You had `hg` in `/usr/bin` at some point, and ran it from that shell. Now you've removed `/usr/bin/hg`. You need to tell your running shell to forget this location:

```
hash hg
```

A new shell wouldn't have this problem, since the cache isn't shared between shell instances.

Comment: Thanks!! So simple, but takes hours to discover if you stay in the same shell.